# Invalid Initializer inside function

Tags: c

I don't know why the below code give invalid Initializer error. Is there something wrong?

```
void ssd_write(uint8_t data){

        uint8_t txBuffer[1] = data;    <--- error

        i2cTransaction.slaveAddress = 0x78;
        i2cTransaction.writeBuf   = txBuffer;
        i2cTransaction.writeCount = 1;
        i2cTransaction.readBuf    = NULL;
        i2cTransaction.readCount  = 0;
        I2C_transfer(i2c, &i2cTransaction);
        I2C_close(i2c);

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
uint8_t txBuffer[1] = {data};
```

Yoou are declaring an array of 1 element and initializing it. You should be aware that in this case you are assigning to `writeBuf` the decayed pointer pointing to the array's first element.

Otherwise you are simply doing an invalid operation by trying to assign the variable to the declared array.

Or more simply you might wanted (Because it is illogical to have an array to store just a single value - you can but that's hardly the thing we do)

```
uint8_t txBuffer = data;
```

After you do this, you might want to do `i2cTransaction.writeBuf   = &txBuffer;` if it expects a `uint8_t*`.

Comment: ... and in the scalar approach, one then assigns `i2cTransaction.writeBuf = &txBuffer` (i.e. one assigns *the address* of `txBuffer` instead of assigning `txBuffer` itself).

Comment: @JohnBollinger.: Edited. The difference between two and all

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois.: Edited.